# Integration google Ima SDK and IMA DAI SDK at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ads

I want to create an ios application that will consist of a video player and its ability to show **IMA DAI** ads and **IMA** ads.

After going through the documentation of both types

- https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/dai
- https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/client-side

I was able to play each alone, what I am trying to achieve is to show both ADS (**IMA DAI** ads and **IMA** ads) on the same Player.

What I am currently doing is the following: Loading the IMA ads and once the ads are done I am stopping it then hide the player and load the DAI ads with a different player.

But it is taking time to load and I am not sure it is the right way to do it, is there any other solution that could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code showing what you tried so far.

Comment: @RazvanS. the code that I have is the same as in the documentation shared previously nothing special.

Comment: Is it a "waterfall" call or a "parallel" workflow you want to achieve ?

Comment: @rabsom parallel workflow, i am trying set the player the will load the two types of ADs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads), both respond to different use case :

- **IMA client-side SDK** : you handle your player yourself (it only brings the adserver abilities)

> With IMA client-side SDKs, you maintain control of content video
> playback, while the SDK handles ad playback. Ads play in a separate
> video player positioned on top of the app's content video player.

- **IMA DAI SDK** : you look for a complete solution from Google (handling both player and adserver)

> With IMA DAI SDKs, apps make a stream request for ad and content
> video—either VOD or live content. The SDK then returns a combined
> video stream, so that you don't have to manage switching between ad
> and content video within your app.

I am afraid you will have to make a choice. And if you look for a wider demand, you might want to choose the DAI one ([here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads) again).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I thought there would be a way to merge them.